# Угол между камерами с проекционной матрицей 3x4

Tags: c++, камера

Есть проекционная матрица 3x4 полученная из R и T в результате стерео калибровки камеры. Как из нее получить угол между камерами?

Comment: Матриц сколько, одна или две?

Comment: Одна. Получена (opencv):
hconcat(R, T, RT2);
R и T из stereoCalibrate

Comment: Получил угол с R

`double dRotDegree = acos((trace(R)[0] - 1) / 2.) * 57.2957795;`

вроде работает правильно.